# Creating a new instance of a class and accessing its instance variables in Python

Tags: python, class, turing-machines

So, I'm building a turing machine in Python, and I've gotten to a point where I need to instantiate my Turing Machine class inside of my parser, but I can't seem to get the syntax right.

Here is the way I'm  defining my TM:

```
class TM(object):
def __init__(self, states, start, accept, reject, alpha, tAlpa, tape, 
transition, head):
    self.states = []
    self.start = start
    self.accept = accept
    self.reject = reject
    self.alpha = []
    self.tAlpha =[]
    self.tape = LinkedList(tape)
    self.transitions = []
    self.head = head
    return;
```

So I need to create an instance in my Parser class:
for example:

```
class Parser:
*some other logic*

tm = TM()
tm.states.append(something)
```

Comment: What code do you have thus far, and what errors is Python throwing?

Comment: When I try and instantiate it like the above example, it asks for arguments to it, but all I need is to be able to access the instance variables of the TM class.

Comment: You've defined a heck of a lot of **_required_** parameters in your `__init__()`. So of course when you dont supply them, you cant instantiate the object!

Comment: It just clicked... I've been looking at it wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Very quick example to show you the effect of required positional arguments:

```
>>> class Temp:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        if kwargs:
            self.temp = kwargs['temp']


>>> t = Temp()
>>> class Temp2:
    def __init__(self, opt1 = None, opt2 = None):
        self.opt1 = opt1
        self.opt2 = opt2


>>> t2 = Temp2()
>>> class Temp3:
    def __init__(self, req, opt1 = None, opt2 = None):
        self.req = req
        self.opt1 = opt1
        self.opt2 = opt2


>>> t3 = Temp3()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#16>", line 1, in <module>
    t3 = Temp3()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'req'
>>>
```

In the first class, `**kwargs` allows me to instantiate and pass any keyword arguments I want. This is a week example, but gets the point across that you can do some initialization checks for existance and then subchecks for key names.

In the second class, by using `... = None` I default the parameter if it isnt supplied. So again, the interpreter is happy because all the parameters received a value!

In the last class, we see the error. Notice that `req` is not defined with a default value. Thus the interpreter demands it receive one to instantiate it. When I dont supply it, you get the `TypeError` telling you so.

In short, without properly instantiating a class, you wont be able to access any of its attributes or use its member functions!

**Edit:** Wanted to explain it in more detail

Further, in OOP/D, try to find ways to steer clear of long `__init__()` function headers. Try something like this instead:

```
>>> class TM:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        init_args = {'states': [],
                 'start': None,
                 'accept': None,
                 'reject': None,
                 'alpha': [],
                 'tAlpha': [],
                 'tape': None, # make later
                 'transitions': [],
                 'head': None}
        for arg, default in init_args.items():
            setattr(self, arg, kwargs.get(arg, default))


>>> tm = TM()
```

Again, using the `**kwargs` to determine when I want to supply values to the object at initialization, but I default it using a pre-defined listing! Breaking it down some:

`init_args` is a ready made dictionary (just like `kwargs`. Dont let the `**` scare you, its just the dictionaries [unpacking operator](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists). Lists have one as well, its literally one `*`.

`for arg, default ... setattr(self, arg, kwargs.get(arg, default))` iterates over our pre-defined arguments container, and then creates a `self.[insert_arg]` attribute with the value from `kwargs.get()`. It looks for `arg` and if it doesnt find it, uses `default` which we already have!

So later when you want to do you single attribute accessing in your `Parser` class:

```
>>> class TM:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        init_args = {'states': [],
                 'start': None,
                 'accept': None,
                 'reject': None,
                 'alpha': [],
                 'tAlpha': [],
                 'tape': None, # make later
                 'transitions': [],
                 'head': None}
        for arg, default in init_args.items():
            setattr(self, arg, kwargs.get(arg, default))


>>> tm = TM()
>>> tm.states.append('it works!')
>>> tm.states
['it works!']
>>>
```